# Selecionar maior valor entre JOINs MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Olá. Preciso fazer uma consulta no MySql onde existem JOINS de 4 tabelas, todas as tabelas tem a coluna data_cadastro, preciso que a seleção retorne apenas o registro onde o data_cadastro for o maior de todas essas tabelas. Como posso fazer isso?

Minha Query atual é:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (`cursos_aulas`) LEFT JOIN `cursos_aulas_arquivos` ON cursos_aulas_arquivos.cursos_aulas_id_fk = cursos_aulas.cursos_aulas_id
                     LEFT JOIN `cursos_aulas_videos` ON cursos_aulas_videos.cursos_aulas_id_fk = cursos_aulas.cursos_aulas_id
                     LEFT JOIN `cursos_aulas_imagens` ON cursos_aulas_imagens.cursos_aulas_id_fk = cursos_aulas.cursos_aulas_id LEFT JOIN `cursos_aulas_exercicios` ON cursos_aulas_exercicios.cursos_aulas_id_fk = cursos_aulas.cursos_aulas_id
WHERE
    cursos_aulas.cedoc_doc_id_fk = '16360'
ORDER BY
    `cursos_aulas_imagens_id` desc,
    `cursos_aulas_arquivos_id` desc,
    `cursos_aulas_videos_id` desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Sua query faz o join de 5 tabelas.

Tente:

```
SELECT *, GREATEST(cursos_aulas_videos.data_cadastro, cursos_aulas_imagens.data_cadastro, cursos_aulas_exercicios.data_cadastro, cursos_aulas_arquivos.data_cadastro) 
FROM `cursos_aulas` 
            LEFT JOIN `cursos_aulas_arquivos` ON cursos_aulas_arquivos.cursos_aulas_id_fk = cursos_aulas.cursos_aulas_id 
            LEFT JOIN `cursos_aulas_videos` ON cursos_aulas_videos.cursos_aulas_id_fk = cursos_aulas.cursos_aulas_id 
            LEFT JOIN `cursos_aulas_imagens` ON cursos_aulas_imagens.cursos_aulas_id_fk = cursos_aulas.cursos_aulas_id 
            LEFT JOIN `cursos_aulas_exercicios` ON cursos_aulas_exercicios.cursos_aulas_id_fk = cursos_aulas.cursos_aulas_id 
WHERE cursos_aulas.cedoc_doc_id_fk = '16360' 
ORDER BY `cursos_aulas_imagens_id`, `cursos_aulas_arquivos_id`, `cursos_aulas_videos_id` desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que um `ORDER BY DESC` no campo `data_cadastro`, seguido de um `LIMIT 1` resolve o seu problema:

```sql
SELECT * FROM cursos_aulas
LEFT JOIN cursos_aulas_arquivos ON cursos_aulas_arquivos.cursos_aulas_id_fk = cursos_aulas.cursos_aulas_id 
LEFT JOIN cursos_aulas_videos ON cursos_aulas_videos.cursos_aulas_id_fk = cursos_aulas.cursos_aulas_id 
LEFT JOIN cursos_aulas_imagens ON cursos_aulas_imagens.cursos_aulas_id_fk = cursos_aulas.cursos_aulas_id 
LEFT JOIN cursos_aulas_exercicios ON cursos_aulas_exercicios.cursos_aulas_id_fk = cursos_aulas.cursos_aulas_id 
WHERE cursos_aulas.cedoc_doc_id_fk = '16360' 
ORDER BY 
      GREATEST(
         cursos_aulas_arquivos.data_cadastro,  
         cursos_aulas_videos.data_cadastro,
         cursos_aulas_imagens.data_cadastro,
         cursos_aulas_exercicios.data_cadastro
         ) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Esqueci de informar um detalhe importante, o campo data_cadastro existe em todos, menos na tabela cursos_aulas. A intenção é pegar a aula que foi cadastrada por último e as aulas estão divididas em tabelas diferentes, uma para aulas em vídeo, outra para áulas em arquivo (pdf, doc e afins) e por ai vai. Ai quero recuperar a última aula cadastrada, comparando os valores do data_cadastro de cada uma delas e retornando só os valores do registro da tabela que contém a aula cadastrada.

Comment: Entendi. Eu editei a minha resposta. Infelizmente não tenho o MySql instalado agora para testar. Veja se o comando funciona